# toPromise doesn't return last observed value

Tags: rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Here is an example that can be run with ts-node. Why is the value displayed in result 2 instead of 3.

```
import { interval, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, takeUntil, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const done = new Subject();
let times = 0;

function test() {
  return interval(5000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
    map(() => times++ ),
    tap(n => {
      console.log(n);
      if (n === 3) {
        done.next();
      }
    }),
    takeUntil(done),
  ).toPromise();
}

test().then(n => {
  console.log('result: ', n);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('error: ', err.message);
});
```

output is: what expecting result: 3

```
0
1
2
3
result:  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) : *Emits the values emitted by the source Observable until a notifier Observable emits a value.* So when you call next method of 'done' you practically stop the emissions and complete that observable, so in the end '3' is never emitted.
[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ujwjbg?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) is a good example, very similar to your case, which demonstrate takeUntil behavior.
If you want to emit '3' maybe you can change your condition to:

```
if (n > 3) {
   done.next();
 }
```